# Получить ответ сайта - 200 или 404 от URL сайта на android

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Мне необходимо получить ответ от сайта 200 или 404 в переменную. Создал поток, но никак не могу разобраться как получить данный URL. Подскажите в myUrlCon какая переменная отвечает за ответ сервера и как её внедрить в данный код? Спасибо!

```java
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                URL myUrl = null;
                try {
                    myUrl = new URL("http://pro-java.ru");
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("ОШИБКА");

                }
                HttpURLConnection myUrlCon =
                        null;
                try {
                    myUrlCon = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("ОШИБКА");
                }

                System.out.println("Метод запроса: " +
                        myUrlCon.getRequestMethod());

                try {
                    System.out.println("ТЕСТ: " +
                            myUrlCon.getResponseMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


               System.out.println("Метод запроса: " +
                        myUrlCon.getResponseMessage());



            }
        }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить код ответа сервера можно следующим образом:

```
myUrlCon = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
myUrlCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
int responsecode = myUrlCon.getResponseCode(); // код ответа сервера
```

Comment: Вылетает ошибка                                 try {
                    int responsecode = myUrlCon.getResponseCode();
                    System.out.println("Код ответа: " +
                            responsecode);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } если сделать такой код в моём примере, то бъёт ошибку

Comment: Какая ошибка? С 9 андроида по умолчанию http трафик приводит к вылетам. Тестируйте на сайте с https, либо [включайте в манифесте](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565) - в потоке этом видимо нельзя запускать .. изменил на https

Comment: @yong, "тяжелые" операции нельзя выполнять в UI потоке. Нужно использовать либо `AsyncTask` либо `Thread`